# Can the opportunity be the parent and child object?

Tags: roll-up-summary

We have two Opportunity record types: Parent and Child. I've added a lookup field on the Child record to be able to link it to its parent record. Hence, there is a "Child Opportunities" related list on the Parent record.

I would like to be able to roll-up the "Child Opportunities" record count and sum.

I've set this up and nothing is happening. Are we able to have the Opportunity object as the parent and child?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rollup summary fields are only available when you have a master-detail relationship, and we can't create master-detail relationships on a single object (another way to say that is that a self-relationship cannot be a master-detail relationship).

This can, however, be accomplished via a trigger and a SOQL query. Instead of making your own trigger for that, though, you should consider using Andrew Fawcett's [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) tool

Comment: I'm actually using the Declarative Lookup Rollup Summary tool, and it's not pulling the information.